# How to change the border thickness and color of an autosuggestbox in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, styling

I want to change the border thickness and border brush of autosuggest box in UWP. But the change is not reflecting in the view.

Here is my code:

`<Autosuggest Box border thickness="0.5" border brush="gray"/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From AutoSuggestBox's template resources, you can see that this control contains a TextBox.

Modify the relevant properties.

```
<Page.Resources>

    <Style x:Key="NewTextBoxStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0.5"/>
    </Style>
    
    <Style x:Key="NewStyle" TargetType="AutoSuggestBox">
        <Setter Property="TextBoxStyle" Value="{StaticResource NewTextBoxStyle}" />
    </Style>
    
</Page.Resources>


<Grid>
    
    <AutoSuggestBox Style="{StaticResource NewStyle}"/>

</Grid>
```

If you need to modify other control properties in the future, you can first view the default style and composition structure of the control in [generic.xaml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.autosuggestbox?view=winrt-22621#control-style-and-template), and then modify the property.

> For design purposes, generic.xaml is available in the (Program
> Files)\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP
> \Generic folder from a Windows Software Development Kit
> (SDK) installation.